# usage of 'By which' in this sentence

Tags: grammar, relative-adverbs

I still don't understand this 'by which' in this sentence.
In my perspective this sentence make sense without 'by which'.
Is there a difference between the two sentences below?

- There is no objective standard **by which** to measure it
- There is no objective standard to measure it

Comment: We usually measure something *by* or *against* something else. Another way to say your first example would be "There is no objective standard to measure it **by**" or "There's no objective standard to measure it **against**."

Answer (score 1):

Your question concerns these sentences:

> There is no objective standard by which to measure it.
>   There is no objective standard to measure it.

The difference between the two sentences is that the second omits the preposition that is taken by the verb *measure*. This is usually either *by,*  *against*, or *with*. The first sentence includes the preposition, and is written to avoid violating a now seldom-observed "rule" against ending a sentence with a preposition. An alternative version of the first sentence is:

> There is no objective standard to measure it **by**.

You ask whether the infinitive must be introduced by the preposition phrase *by which.* The answer to that is that it need not be, but that in English this is the way we customarily talk about *measuring.* We measure something *against*, *with*, or *by* something else, such as an *objective standard*.

The verb *measure* here is transitive, and defined by the OED as:

> c. trans. To bring into comparison, opposition, or competition *with*; to match *with*; to compare **against**.

The noun *standard* in this sentence conforms to the OED's 10th definition, which is:

> a. (Originally fig. from 9.) An authoritative or recognized exemplar of correctness, perfection, or some definite degree of any quality.

Among the citations in support of this definition, we see:

> <sup>1665   R. Boyle Occas. Refl. v. v. sig. Ll1v   Men will be asham'd to be unlike those, whose Customs and Deportments pass for the Standards, **by which** those of other Men are to be measur'd.</sup>

Modern examples of *"by which to measure"* also abound.

- [Bankrate](http://www.bankrate.com/financing/retirement/a-gauge-by-which-to-measure-your-assets/) presents *"A gauge by which to measure your assets"*.
- [The Albuquerque Journal](https://www.abqjournal.com/611165/nation-needs-standard-by-which-to-measure-education.html) tells us that the *"Nation needs standard by which to measure education"*.
- [ProjectManager.com](https://www.projectmanager.com/training/how-to-measure-project-success) explains that *"you will have a better rule by which to measure your project"* if you "extend your metric".

Comment: it's seldom-observed rule.. no wonder how hard to understand. Thank you so much for an explanation. it's hard to understand for my level of english. I might have to forget this grammar for my mental heath .